# Android - store and load files in project root

Tags: java, android, storage

I am looking for an appropriate way to store and access pdf files in my Android app.

The problem is: I have 5 pdf-files which I would like to store in the project resources and load in the app.

I have tried to make a new directory in the project root `/myApp/pdfs`, and accessing it by:

```
File myFile = new File("/myApp/pdfs/,fileName);
```

I have tried some different variants of the path name: `./myApp/pdfs`, `myApp/pdfs`, `/pdfs`, `./pdfs`. However I get the same message stating that the file can't be found.

How do I get the path to my apps directory? And is this the most appropriate approach for saving a small number of pdf-files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to load the pdfs from the app (while the app is running), you probably want to store them in the res/raw folder.